# Get all the keys of an array and in case the key has no value, return the value

Tags: php

I've just come across a problem, which apparently looks simple, but I can't find a solution. I have the following array in PHP:

```
[
  "name" => "user"
  0 => "created_at"
  "email" => "mail"
]
```

And I need to get an array like this:

```
[
  "name"
  "created_at"
  "email"
]
```

As you can see, I only need to obtain the original keys from the array, but in case a value from the original array does not have an associated value, then return the value instead of the key.

I have tried several ways using the following methods:

```
array_flip()
array_keys()
array_values()
```

I would appreciate in advance anyone who could help me.

Comment: Probably will need `array_map` and then your own function to check if they key is numerical.

Comment: @user3783243 I had thought of that initially, but I don't know if it is the most efficient way to achieve it

Comment: What if the key is `""` or `" "` or `"."`? Does that count as "not a value?"

Comment: @kmoser good point! That would also count as value, at least in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array and add the desired values to your new array:

```
$a = [
  "name" => "user",
  0 => "created_at",
  "email" => "mail",
];

$b = [];
foreach ( $a as $k => $v ) {
    $b[] = ( $k ? $k : $v );
}

print_r($b);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => name
    [1] => created_at
    [2] => email
)
*/
```

For a more sophisticated determination of which key(s) to keep, replace the first `$k` in the ternary expression with a function that tests `$k` for validity:

```
$b[] = ( test($k) ? $k : $v );
// ...
function test($k) {
  return ! is_number($k); // For example
}
```

Answer (score 1):

is just a simple foreach

```
<?php

$test=
[
  "name" => "user"
  ,0 => "created_at"
  ,"email" => "mail"
];

$res=[];
foreach(array_keys($test) as $ch){
    (is_numeric($ch) and ($res[]=$test[$ch])  )or ($res[]=$ch);
}
var_dump($res);

?>
```